# How to access the same IP using different network interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, ip, tcp

I have three wlan interfaces attached in my RaspberryPi:

- `wlan0`
- `wlan1`
- `wlan2`

Each of them is connected to the **different SSID**:

- `gopro-0`
- `gopro-1`
- `gopro-2`

GoPro cameras are set as a WiFi router, have **always the same IP address**: `10.5.5.9`.

With this configuration if I call:

```
curl http://10.5.5.9
```

then first `wlan0` interface will be used (simplified assumption). If I'd like to call the camera `gopro-2`, I hve to invoke:

```
curl http://10.5.5.9 --interface wlan2
```

It works. However there is a problem that not all commands allows me to specify the interface (i.e. `ffmpeg` - or I don't know about it).

Is it possible to somehow trick Linux and *delegate* some IP address to be forwarded to `10.5.5.9` on specific interface?

For example:

```
10.5.4.100 -> 10.5.5.9 @ wlan0
10.5.4.101 -> 10.5.5.9 @ wlan1
10.5.4.102 -> 10.5.5.9 @ wlan2
```

I would appreciate any solution or even other approach that will let me call the same IP on different interface using regular HTTP GET/POST methods.

Comment: The clean solution is obviously to assign different IP addresses to the gopro's. Why is this not possible?

Comment: @dirkt Each GoPro camera - if works as a hotspot - creates wlan network with SSID that I can specify, but their IP addresses are always fixed: `10.5.5.9` - there is no possibility to change it.

Comment: That sounds really broken. I'd use iptables with `SNAT` (incoming) and `DNAT` (outgoing) targets to map IPs depending on the interface, as you suggested. Make sure the routing tables match. I can't write rules for you because I can't test them without the hardware setup.

Comment: See also: https://cam-do.com/pages/ip-address-changer

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen that seems to be the best solution: fix the brokenness so that the workaround I've no longer necessary

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue for a different type of device and figured out a way to do it. You need a combination of iptables mangle and ip route

Give each interface a unique IP(192.168.44.8 below) on the same subnet as the device. In this example the virtual IP for the first device is 192.168.44.9

My physical devices were all at 192.168.44.1 on 4 different interfaces and with this pattern and the virtual IPs I could reliably communicate with all of them.

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.44.9 -j MARK --set-mark 0x01

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark 0x01 -d 192.168.44.9 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.44.1

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 0x01 --destination 192.168.44.1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.44.8
```

With this in place, now add the following routes.

```
ip route add 192.168.44.0/24 dev eth4 table 1
ip rule add from all fwmark 1 table 1
ip route flush cache
```

You can repeat this pattern any number of times, just keep increment the mark
and the addresses for how ever many interfaces you have.

Hopefully this will be useful to others dealing with duplicate addresses on different network interfaces.

Comment: These commands don't seem to work. I would expect to be able to do `ping 192.168.44.9` and end up hitting `192.168.44.1`. Is there a step missing? Do you have to  create a VLAN or something that is set to 192.168.1.9?

Comment: This was very helpful!
Now how would be the setup to achieve the opposite operation?
I mean redirecting packets from:
* wlan0 -> 10.5.4.100
* wlan1 -> 10.5.4.101
* wlan2 -> 10.5.4.102

Answer (score 0):

I think the way is to use iptables, and set routes for that. Here is a similar answer for the question that you asked:

https://serverfault.com/questions/345111/iptables-target-to-route-packet-to-specific-interface

This is a bit less complex in OpenBSD/pf.

Answer (score 0):

The very same problem was described on this thread:
https://forum.developer.parrot.com/t/multiple-parrot-anafi-controlled-via-olympe-on-linux-configure-ip/9590/2

It gives a complete solution, that indeed uses both `iptables` rules and routing